# How to sum and group MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table (see pic.):

[image]

I need to `sum(AT_amount)` and group by `AT_balance_tax_id` .

But at the same time I need to get all `AT_balance_tax_type_id` for all groupped rows, of course without `name` duplications.

How to do that, I tried:

```
SELECT t.*
     , i.*
     , ABS(SUM(AT_amount)) amount 
  FROM account_transactions t
  JOIN balance_tax_invoices i
    ON i.id = t.AT_balance_tax_id 
 WHERE AT_createuser = 15 
 GROUP 
    BY AT_balance_tax_id
     , AT_balance_tax_type_id 
 ORDER 
    BY AT_transactiondatetime DESC
```

It returns me not all `AT_balance_tax_type_id` for groupped rows.

Result is:

[image]

I expect this data for `AT_balance_tax_id`:

```
AT_amount    AT_balance_tax_id     AT_balance_tax_type_id
33000         9                    1, 1, 3, 3
```

Delete duplicates:

```
AT_amount    AT_balance_tax_id     AT_balance_tax_type_id
33000         9                    1, 3
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is 9 and 33000 in your expected results? Why don't you post valid sample data and expected results and explain what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `*` in the select clause. MySQL group by clause automatically includes other columns listed in select cause but not in Group By clause.

Also it seems you need [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function with distinct caluse. You can modify your query to -

```
SELECT at.`AT_balance_tax_id`
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT at.`AT_balance_tax_type_id`)
      ,ABS(SUM(AT_amount)) AS amount
FROM `account_transactions` at
INNER JOIN `balance_tax_invoices` bi ON bi.`id` = at.`AT_balance_tax_id`
WHERE `AT_createuser` = 15
GROUP BY at.`AT_balance_tax_id`
ORDER BY at.`AT_transactiondatetime` DESC
```

Also I have used aliases to increase the readability of query.

Comment: The same result, I have attached pic for you querty

Comment: Please post what is your expected output?

Comment: Okay, could I collect by `AT_balance_tax_id` and get all `AT_balance_tax_type_id`like `1,3,2`?

Comment: This didn't tell me anything. Please post the data you want.

Comment: I posted what I expect